# Mounting /home as noexec

Tags: linux, security, web-server, hosting, mount

Does mounting `/home` with `noexec` really add security?

All it does is disable binary execution right? So that means other scripts can still run and execute shell code into services.

Run shared hosting.

Does mounting `/tmp`, `/var/tmp` and `/var/shm` with `noexec,nodev` and all provide security?

Comment: Stupid close! This is a very important question about the effectiveness of security options. And it is important to know against which threads `noexec` helps and against which not. The questioner has good reasons to bring `noexec` on home directories in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will disable execution in any form. If it will add value to security depends on the network and purpose of this network.

Comment: I guess that /bin/bash /home/peter/foo.sh would still work.

Comment: Disable execution in any form? Such PHP or just ./script ?
So really, noexec does not offer any protection if /bin/bash works